# Flutter not found error on macOS though ive set up path variable in bash_profile

Tags: bash, flutter

I tried installing flutter on my macOS, but whenever i run flutter command on terminal it says flutter not found. Ive extracted the Flutter SDK in Application folder and ive added the path in .bash_profile. still it did not work. [Attaching the Bash file and terminal screenshots here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMkua.png)

Path which i added is - 
`export PATH="/Users/ritishkannayagari/Applications/flutter/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: What does it show when you run command: echo $PATH? Did you run command: source ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: @PhucTran i saved the path in bash_profile and then run the source ~/.bash_profile and did echo $PATH, but when i run the terminal on new window then it again shows flutter command not found

Comment: Echo Path before i run source ~/.bash_profile -
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

And then echo $PATH after running `source~/.bash_profile` is 


`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/ritishkannayagari/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ritishkannayagari/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/ritishkannayagari/Applications/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
`
@PhucTran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `zsh` in your terminal. You can either :

- switch to `bash` in your terminal :

Terminal > Preferences > Shells open with: `/bin/bash`

---

- keep `zsh` and add flutter PATH to `~/.zshrc`

```sh
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/Applications/flutter/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Then restart Terminal

---

- keep `zsh` add `source ~/.bash-profile` in your `~/.zshrc`

```sh
echo 'source ~/.bash-profile' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how do i do that?